# querying the graphDB(cypher)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to explain the nodes and relationships between them:

1. `(CR)-[:HAS]->(SR)`
2. `(CR)-[:TAGGED_TO]->(KEYWORDS)`
3. `(SR)-[:TAGGED_TO]->(KEYWORDS)`

So, I have 3 types of nodes (`CR`, `SR` and `KEYWORDS`) and 2 relationships (`HAS` and `TAGGED_TO`).

One `CR` has many `SR` attached to it, one `CR` can be tagged to many `KEYWORDS` and also one `SR` can be tagged to many `KEYWORDS`, one or more `KEYWORDS` can be common in `CR` and `SR`.

Suppose we have 4 given keywords, now we need to find 4 columns from my query:

- 1st column: Those `CR` which has matched `KEYWORDS`.
- 2nd column: Number of `SR` attached to those `CR` which came out in column 1.
- 3rd column: Count of those `KEYWORDS` which got matched with the `CR` which came out in 1 st column.
- 4th column: number of unique keywords matched with the `SR` which comes in column 2.

I have written a query which is able to achieve first 3 column but not getting the 4 column.

```
WITH ["level","transact","balance","line"] AS coll
WITH coll, range(0, size(coll)-1) AS is
UNWIND is AS i
WITH coll[i] as col, i
match (s:SR)-[t:TAGGED_TO]->(tg:Tag) where tg.name=~('.*'+col+'.*') 
with  s, count(t) as no_of_keywords
matched_in_SR  match (s:SR)<-[h:HAS]-(c:CR) 
return c.CR_Number,count(h) as NO_of_SR_under_CR_which_contain_keywords, 
no_of_keywords_matched_in_SR
```

Image of output console

[image]

In my output console I have 3 columns

1. CR_number
2. no_of_keywords_matched_to_that_CR
3. Number_of_SR_attached_to_that_CR.

In 4 th column i want number of keywords matched out of the given keywords to that SRs which comes in 3 rd column.

For example CR 1-11071804441 has 2 keywords matched out of 4 given keywords and 893 SR are attached to it.

I want 4th column which will contain the count of keywords out of given 4 keywords that are matched to 893 SR  which comes in 3 rd column.

For an instance suppose out of 893 SR 1st SR contains 2 keywords out of 4 given keyword and 2nd SR contain again same 2 keywords which 1 st SR contained (so we will not count those 2 keywords) and a new keyword out of the given 4 keywords so my total count will become 3 like that we have to count the keywords for all 893 SR which are attached to CR 1-11071804441 in 1st column. Like that total maximum count of keywords matched to the SR would be 4 because we have in total 4 given keywords.Like that i have to populate my 4 th column for all the CR_number

Comment: I think the title of your question is too broad. Please, edit it. Also, can you share a sample data and the expected result? Maybe a [Neo4j Console](http://console.neo4j.org/).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @BrunoPeres . I have added more info and the image of output console as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
... WITH col               
MATCH (s:SR)-[:HAS]-(c:CR)-[:TAGGED_TO]-(tg:Tag) 
WHERE tg.name=~('.*'+col+'.*') 
WITH c, tg, s 
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:TAGGED_TO]-(tg1:Tag)
WHERE tg1.name=~('.*'+col+'.*')
RETURN c.CR_Number as CR_number, 
 count(distinct tg) as NO_of_keywords_matched_in_CR, 
 count(distinct s) as NO_of_SR_under_CR_which_contain_keywords, 
 count(distinct tg1) as NO_of_keywords_matched_in_SR
```

In the first `MATCH`, the query matches all the `CR`s that have your required keywords, plus all the `SR`s attached to those `CR`s.

In the second `OPTIONAL MATCH`, the query matches all the `Tag`s attached to the previously fetched `SR`s. The reason the second match is `OPTIONAL` is because there might be `SR`s that may not have any `Tag`s attached to them (a normal MATCH would filter your `SR`s to only return the ones that have at least on tag attached).

Comment: Thanks @imran. Actually want CR_no. in 1st column &for 4th column :-If we see 2nd row of image,CR has 1 keyword attched to it out of 4 given keywords and 385 SR are attched to it .Now in the 4 column of output i want how many keywords these 385 SR contain out of 4 given keywords.for e.g. out of these 385 suppose 1 st SR contain 2 keywords matched out of 4 given keywords and 2nd SR contain same those 2 keywords and 1new keyword so,count becomes 3 like that we have to count for 385 SR and put against CR in 2nd row as 4th column (so max.count'll go 4 as we have only 4 given keywords in our case)

Comment: @Rajat i have updated the query based on your update. If it doesn't work as expected, can you please share some input data set to test the query against